# Is there any regex that will help me choose the anchors only with certain class?

Tags: php, regex, web-crawler, domdocument

I want to extract the `href` of the anchor having only certain class with it like `link-wrapper`.

So, this means I will have the href of the link like:

```
<a href="blaa..blaa" class="link-wrapper">click here</a>
```

P.S. It should extract both the links if they are aligned in sequential manner like:

```
<a href="blaa" class="link-wrapper">link-1</a><a href="blaa" class="link-wrapper">link-2</a>
```

I tried the solutions already present in the stack-overflow, but none suited my problem. Since some of them were in java-script and other languages. I tried looking for DOMDocument, but its bit difficult to exactly match the solution.

I tied some of the preg_match which didn't worked for me, like:

```
preg_match('/<a(?:(?!class\=")(?:.|\n))*class\="(?:(?!link\-wrapper)(?:.|\n))*link\-wrapper(?:(?!<\/a>)(?:.|\n))*<\/a>/i', $content, $output_array);
```

Comment: Don't parse HTML using regex. Use something like [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [`DOMXPath`](https://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to get your results. First load the HTML into a `DOMDocument` and then use an XPath query to find all the anchors that have class including `link-wrapper` e.g.

```
$html = '<a href="blaa..blaa" class="link-wrapper">click here</a><a href="not.blaa" class="something-else">link-3</a>
<a href="blaa" class="link-wrapper">link-1</a><a href="blaa..again" class="link-wrapper">link-2</a>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach ($xpath->query('//a[contains(@class, "link-wrapper")]') as $a) {
    $urls[] = $a->attributes->getNamedItem('href')->nodeValue;
}
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    echo "$url\n";
}
```

Output:

```
blaa..blaa 
blaa 
blaa..again
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/g3iIO)

Comment: thank you so much, this code seems to fit for the requirement. Also you represented the solution so good. Thank you again.